# where are usb movies stored once downloaded

Tags: usb, download, file-location

I borrowed a USB from a friend with some movies which I downloaded to my computer over a month ago. Unfortunately the movies weren't named so it was just files without names. I want To watch one but cant find it anyhwere, how do I find where they have gone on my PC

Comment: 'Files without names'? o_O

Comment: @WeiShi, I think they meant like `vid1.mpg`, `vid2.mpg`—at least that’s the best I can psychic out. (For the record, you can have files without names and files without extensions, but annoyingly enough, not *both*. ¬_¬)

Comment: @TORY, you’re going to have to be (a lot) more specific. When you say you borrowed a “USB from a friend”, do you mean a flash-drive? When you say you downloaded them to your computer, do you mean you copied the files through the OS? What OS, Windows? What do you mean by “not named”? What program did you use to watch them?

Answer (score 1):

If you "downloaded" it to your computer then you would have known what folder it has gone into. If you played them straight from the USB they wouldn't have been saved to your computer.

That said, you can always do a search for *.avi, *.mp4, *.mpg, *.mpeg, *.mkv, or *.wmv those are some of the most common formats they would have been saved as if they were saved somewhere on your computer.

Comment: thanks everyone, I am using windows 7, and yes I copied the files from a flash drive. When I say not named, the files themselves did not have the names of the movies, I cant remember what it said but definately not the movie names as I have done a search for them and they are not there. I watched them through VLC media player. I will do the avi, mp4 search etc and see if I can find them.

Comment: Guess what searching for the avi files found them all, silly me this was driving me nuts thanks JKM